# Why does the compiler tell me "actionPerformed method not implemented"?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TalkClock clock = new TalkClock();
    clock.start(1000, true);
    System.out.println("xxxx");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quit program?");
    System.exit(0);

  }
}

class TalkClock
{
  public void start(int interval, boolean beep){
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() 
      {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          System.out.println("At the tone, the time is " + new Date());
          if (beep) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
      };
    Timer t = new Timer(interval, listener);
    t.start();
  }
}
```

I run it in my Mac. The error is

```
hello.java:24: error: <anonymous TalkClock$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
      {
      ^
1 error
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have, including the `import` statements at the top. Also include the complete exact error message you get with all the information available.

Comment: Did you by any chance write another class called `ActionEvent`? Btw, you should use the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: @manikantanvsr Please don't make suggested code improvements in questions via edit requests.

Comment: I can’t reproduce. I can run your method without seeing any sign of error. Are you getting your error message at compile time or runtime?

Comment: @khelwood I try to use ```@Override```. But it has one more error "hello.java:25: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        ```@Override```
        ^
2 errors"

Comment: @OleV.V.  Sorry, I renew my question and show the error.It's compile error.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you ~

Answer (score 2):

You import the ActionEvent from JavaFX. You need to import the swing class.